# Is there a way to search for the last email that I sent to an address in outlook in python?

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32, win32com, office-automation

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to search for the last email that I sent to an address in my Outlook sent folder, and to reply all to that. It’s probably just me, but the win32 module‘s documentation is very hard to follow.

Comment: Is this not a feature in outlook itself? Searching by recipient seems like a pretty basic feature...

Comment: I should have been more specific. I want to iterate through a list of emails (typically hundreds) and reply all to the last email sent to each email address. Can’t figure out if there is a function for this in Python win32.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to iterate over all items in the folder in that case. Instead, you can use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class from the Outlook object model to get items that were sent to a specific recipient (email address). Read more about these methods in the following articles that I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

For example, you could use the following search criteria to find items that were sent to the sample email address (VBA syntax):

```
criteria = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:to" & Chr(34) & " like '%sample@email.com%'"
```

See [Filtering Items Using a String Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-a-string-comparison) for more information.

Then you can sort the found items and get the latest one from the `Items` collection.

As soon as you find the required item you may call the [ReplyAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.replyall(method)) method.